# Maschler's bargaining set

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, game-theory

I want to describe the Maschelr's bargaining set $\cal M$ which says

that $x\in \cal M$ is $x$ if it is in the imputation $X$ and to any objection there is a counter objection.

In my opinion

$x \in {\cal M} \iff x \in X \land (A \Rightarrow B)$

where A is denoting the objection and B the counter-objection.

**BUT** I've got the following hint from a trusted source:

$$x\in {\cal M} \iff x\in X \land A \land B.$$

Is there any intuition behind this hint ?
I would prefer my variant by now I'm not sure why the source says the true thing.