# Mind boggling text in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, game-theory

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.00409.pdf)

I do not follow on the first page this boldface part of the sentence:

By
the foregoing reasoning it should be clear that we are only allowed to reason with **known true
statements, that is, we are not allowed to assume that a proof for $\varphi$ or $\psi$ exists.** Doing so, leads
immediately to a wrong conclusion.

I'd say that if a proof exists then $\psi$ is true ?
So what is the distinction between provable and true, does one imply the other
aka Post theorem ? Why this doesn't work in game theory ?

Comment: He is saying you have to **know** that the proof exists; you cannot just **assume** that it exists. I don't know if his thesis is correct, but there is a difference between using an established fact and simply assuming a fact.

Comment: At a first glance that looks like a crackpot paper.

Comment: I think the point he's trying to make is that if, in a model, both $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are true, that's not enough to demonstrate that $\varphi \vdash \psi$ (even though the model does satisfy $\varphi \Vdash \psi$) because there may be some other model satisfying your axioms in which $\varphi$ is true but $\psi$ is false.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think the same but it is of critical importance for me. I'm trying to discover a subtle mistake in my thesis and the paper is very close to it. And also well written.

Comment: The author's e-mail gets listed in that paper.  Maybe you can't contact that e-mail since it's behind a university system, but it did get listed, so maybe the best course of action lies in sending an e-mail to the author of the text for clarification?

Comment: Statement: "If today is a Monday, then tomorrow is a Tuesday". This seems like a true fact. But is there a proof? No. It is more a matter of convention. What if the world community decides to skip one day, so that Monday January first 2050 is followed by Wednesday January third 2050 ?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I'm not sure how you think university email systems work, but they certainly do not block email from outside the university! The whole point of listing your email on a paper is to make it possible for readers to contact you (so I agree with your advice).

Comment: From the article: "if we have a proof of $\phi \vdash \varphi$, then we also have a proof of $\phi \to \varphi$. Thus, if we have anaged to prove the clauses $\phi$ and $\varphi$, they are known true statements of a calculus system from which the provability of $\phi \vdash \varphi$ can be obtained." IMO this is not correct: $\phi \vdash \varphi$ means that we have a proof in the calculus of $\varphi$ **from** assumption $\phi$. It is not necessary that we have a proof in the calculus of $\phi$.

Comment: The following comment about the incorrect reading of the "conditional statement like $¬A \to A$" is fine; in classical logic this is simply $A \lor A$ i.e. $A$ (as written by the author). What is puzzling is the following statement that "a representation of an indirect proof by $¬A \vdash A$." The rule of Indirect Proof is: "if $\Gamma, \lnot A \vdash \bot$, then $\Gamma \vdash A$."

Comment: What is puzzling to me is the discussion (page 4-5) about $\lnot (A \land \lnot B)$. If we assume $(A \land \lnot B)$ and we derive a contradiction $\bot$ from it, we conclude with $\lnot (A \land \lnot B)$ that - in **classical logic** - is exactly $(A \to B)$. Fullstop.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of what exactly you are trying to ask but what I can say with regards to the question is the following:

You are correct in that if a proof exists, then the statement is true. However, the text is saying that the converse is not necessarily true. In other words, a statement being true does not require the existence of a proof. Take for example, the existence of 0 such that 1+0=1. This is true, but there is no proof for it, because we defined it this way axiomatically. Due to incompleteness, there will always be statements in any logical system that are true and cannot be proven per se.

Comment: which of these equivalences fall under he realm of the paper: $$x \in X \land \neg (A \land B) \iff x \in X \land (\neg A \vee \neg B) \iff x \notin \cal M$$ **or** $$x \in {\cal M} \iff x \in X \land (A \Rightarrow B) ?$$ The symbols $A,B,\cal M$ are defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278349/maschlers-bargaining-set).
Holger says that only the first and I cannot conclude why not the mine, the second one.

Comment: "Due to incompleteness, there will always be statements in any logical system that are true and cannot be proven per se."  No.  Many formulations of classical propositional calculus is complete.  Indeed, Goedel's doctoral thesis, reportedly (I haven't read it), proved that some formulation for first-order predicate calculus was complete.  Presburger Arithmetic is complete.  Skolem Arithmetic is complete.  Incompleteness is not a universal characteristic of all systems, and Goedel didn't claim such either.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood But here everything is decidable. It is not a matter of incompleteness. There is some point which I've failed to understand so far. Why the second formula from my comment above is not the right one ?